# Execution failed for task ':checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. Androidx and jetified are both enabled but still receive errors

Tags: java, android, gradle

As the title states, I'm getting duplicate class errors when trying to implement dialogfragments. The following implementation is what triggers the errors, but it is the necessary implementation for the dialog fragment import.

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat found in modules jetified-main.jar (main.jar) and media-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CallbackHandler found in modules jetified-main.jar (main.jar) and media-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback found in modules jetified-main.jar (main.jar) and media-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback$ConnectionCallbackInternal found in modules jetified-main.jar (main.jar) and media-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.media:media:1.0.0)
```

Most other similar problems get solved by setting

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in the gradle.properties file. However, I have already migrated to androidx and set both of these to true and my problem persists.

My build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
//        mavenCental()
//        maven {
//            url 'https://jitpack.io'
//        }
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'idea'

dependencies {
    //for android rest
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20160212'

    // may be empty used by the autobuilder
    //implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    //implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    compileOnly fileTree(dir: '../../ATAK/libs', include: '*.jar')
    compileOnly fileTree(dir: '../../ATAK/build/libs', include: '*.jar')
    compileOnly fileTree(dir: '../../MapCoreInterfaces/build/libs', include: '*.jar')
    compileOnly fileTree(dir: '../../ATAKMapEngine/build/libs', include: '*.jar')
    compileOnly fileTree(dir: '../../ATAKMapEngine/libs', include: '*.jar')

    // strictly for the plugin sdk
    compileOnly fileTree(dir: '../..', include: '*.jar')


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    //implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

}

def getSvnRevision() {
    new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
        def result = exec {
            executable = 'svn'
            args = ['info']
            standardOutput = os
            ignoreExitValue = true
        }
        def outputAsString = os.toString()
        def matchLastChangedRev = outputAsString =~ /Revision: (\d+)/
        def length = matchLastChangedRev.size()
        if (length > 0)
            ext.svnRev = "${matchLastChangedRev[0][1]}".toInteger()
        else
            ext.svnRev = 1
    }

    return svnRev
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }


    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("android_keystore")
            storePassword "tnttnt"
            keyAlias "wintec_mapping"
            keyPassword "tnttnt"
        }

        release {
            storeFile file("android_keystore")
            storePassword "tnttnt"
            keyAlias "wintec_mapping"
            keyPassword "tnttnt"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            System.setProperty("atak.proguard.mapping", "../../ATAK/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt")
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-gradle.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            defaultConfig.versionCode = getSvnRevision()
            defaultConfig.versionName = getSvnRevision()
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']


        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        //instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')

    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 28
    }


}

//task clean(type: Delete) {
//    delete rootProject.buildDir
//}
```

Comment: Try invalidating cache restart clean project rebuild project

Comment: No luck. Anything else I should try?